# Fast way to format doctests

Tags: python, formatting, doctest

Say I write the following function:

```
def my_marvellous_list(my_list):
    return 'What a marvellous list!'
```

and would like to add a doctest, to verify that

```
my_marvellous_list([4, 5, 10, 7, 3, 8, 50, 3, 1, 8, 40, 87, 4, 2, 756756, 20, 10, 5, 30, 5, 543, 7, 8])
```

returns `'What a marvellous list!'`.

Then I would need to modify my function as follows:

```
def my_marvellous_list(my_list):
    """
    >>> my_marvellous_list([4, 5, 10, 7, 3, 8, 50, 3, 1, 8, 40, 87, 4, 2,
    ...      756756, 20, 10, 5, 30, 5, 543, 7, 8])
    'What a marvellous list!'
    """

    return 'What a marvellous list!'
```

In order to insert the test into the docstring, I had to add `>>>` at the beginning of each command, and `...` at the beginning of each hanging indent.

This can get tedious to do by hand - does there exist an automated way of converting pure Python to doctest format?

Answer (score 1):

IPython has a [`%doctest_mode` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-doctest_mode) that will change its prompts to the standard doctest format.

```
In [1]: def my_marvellous_list(my_list):
   ...:     return 'What a marvellous list!'
   ...: 

In [2]: %doctest_mode
Exception reporting mode: Plain
Doctest mode is: ON
>>> my_marvellous_list([4, 5, 10, 7, 3, 8, 50, 3, 1, 8, 40, 87, 4, 2,
...     756756, 20, 10, 5, 30, 5, 543, 7, 8])
'What a marvellous list!'
>>>
```